# MongoDB projection parameter not working in findOne()

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to use a projection parameter on findOne() to extract a single field from a document (stats) but it just seems to return the whole document. I'm using version "mongodb": "^3.4.1" in Node.js

This is the document structure

```
{ _id: 5e563015fa9a1a0134cac3cb,
  username: 'user1',
  password: '1234',
  email: 'user@email.com',
  stats: 
   { totalViewed: 122,
     totalUnique: 4,
     tknow: 80,
     tdknow: 42,
     setCnt: 78 },
  progress: 
   [ { cardId: 1001, knowCnt: 3, dknowCnt: 4 },
     { cardId: 1016, knowCnt: 0, dknowCnt: 0 } ] }
```

This is the code:

```
 var findOneDoc = function() {
        db.collection("testusers").findOne(
          { username: "user1" },
          { stats: 1 }, //field to return
          function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("Error: ", err);
            }
            console.log("Success: ", result);
          }
        );
      };
     findOneDoc();
```

I also tried:`{$project: {stats: 1}}`, to no avail

Thanks

Comment: As a double check, did you try `db.collection["testusers'].findOne({"username":"user1"},{stats:1})` directly from the shell?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with using the shell directly. Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/api/Collection.html#findOne) the `.findOne()` method takes options as a second parameter and it is recommended to use `projection` to define fields:

```
db.collection("testusers").findOne(
    { username: "user1" },
    { projection: { stats: 1 } },
    function(err, result) { ... }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. When I tried this nothing returned from the database - so success or error messages or fields returned. 

 ```var findOneDoc4 = function() {  
    db.collection("testusers").findOne(
    { username: "user1" },
    { projection: { stats: 1 } },
    function(err, result) { 
        if (err) {
              console.log("Error: ", err);
            }
            console.log("Success: ", result); 
    }
  );```

Comment: The document is shown at the top in the original question.  Thanks

Comment: what if you remove second parameter, are you still getting no result?

Comment: If I remove the second parameter the whole document returns as expected.

Comment: Can you try `{ fields: { stats: 1 } }` instead of `{ projection: { stats: 1 } }`?

Comment: Ok. It's working now with your original code. I had several versions running at a time trying to troubleshoot and I think there was a clash in the function calls. My bad. Thankyou.

Comment: Thanks ! Worked for me !

Answer (score 4):

with `findOne` operations, the second parameter passed is an options parameter, so you should pass in your projects within the options parameter, like this:

```
query = { username: "user1" };
options = { projection: { stats: 1 }};

db.collection("testusers").findOne(query, options)
```

Comment: Don't forget to `await`

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like mick said, with findOne

```
await db.collection("testusers").findOne(
    { username: "user1" },
    { projection: { stats: 1 } },
    function(err, result) { ... }
);
```

or you can do it with find, like that

```
await db.collection("testusers")
.find({ username: "user1" })
.limit(1)
.project(["stats"])
.toArray()
```

you can add fields to the array project for more fields

Answer (score 0):

findOne returns a document.  use find()  …..

Comment: I tried .find() but it still didn't return anything. I'm only targeting one document so my understanding is that findOne() should work and is compatible with projection parameters. Thanks