# Want a sub document which is present in document, from MongoDB Database

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, mongo-dart

I have a Json data stored in my MongoDB database as showing below,

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f17109a9013adc57942af2a"),
        "name" : "Demo Name",
        "dob" : "04/01/2000",
        "phone" : "1234567890",
        "email" : "demoname@gmail.com",
        "password" : "0987",
        "cPass" : "0987",
        "location" : "Civil line, Mumbai"
}
```

And I only want an **name** (sub document) i.e Demo Name here from this whole document:

```
: Demo Name
```

I'm writing this query:

```
var employ = await coll.findOne( { "email": "demoname@gmail.com" } );
```

But it gives me whole document in **var employ**. I only want name in var employ. How can I do that with Mongo Dart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB projection parameter not working in findOne()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60536941/mongodb-projection-parameter-not-working-in-findone)

Comment: No, this is talking about mongoDb and node js and I want that query of mongoDB in dart language.

Comment: try two options if it helps 1) add this `.project({'name ':1});` after `findOne()`  or 2) add this in second argument like `findOne({your conditions}, {'name ':1})`

Comment: It is showing the error - error: The method 'project' isn't defined for the type 'SelectorBuilder'. In android studio, But this query definitely works in mongoDB shell. After searching  a lot I got the answer in comment section of one video it is as showing below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query finds the element whose email value is matched with "demoname@gmail.com" and after finding element, It is going to exclude the fields i.e _id, dob, phone, email, password, cPass and location. The value remains is "Demo Name" along with it's key.

```
 var employ = await coll
              .find(where.match("email", "demoname@gmail.com").excludeFields([
                "_id",
                "dob",
                "phone",
                "email",
                "password",
                "cPass",
                "location",
              ]))
              .toList();
```

For removing key we have to use the following code.

```
var arrayEle = employ[0];          // This statement can store the value in arrayEle from zeroth position.
var empName = arrayEle['name'];    // This statement can remove the key "name" and only value of the key i.e "Demo Name" gets stored in empName variable.   
  print(empName);                  // This statment print the value stored in empName which is "Demo Name".
```